# strace print asound ioctl

Tags: debugging, alsa, strace

my strace tends to confuse some `ioctl` values (I'm sure that the `SNDRV` ioctls is not recognized well...)

how I can recognize the right `ioctl` value?

a little example:

`$ strace aplay -l`

```
...
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
ioctl(4, UI_DEV_CREATE, 0xbfaa6e74)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
...
```

that `UI_DEV_CREATE` is a `SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_CARD_INFO`

(another example)

```
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_CONTROL or USBDEVFS_CONTROL32, 0xbfaa6f94) = 0
ioctl(4, UI_DEV_CREATE, 0xbfaa71f0)     = 0
ioctl(4, 0x80045530, 0xbfaa73ac)
```

`USBDEVFS_CONTROL` is a `SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_PVERSION`
and I really don't know what is the Macro expansion for `0x80045530`...

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [`Documentation/ioctl/ioctl-number.txt`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/ioctl/ioctl-number.txt#n170), the value 0x55 (`'U'`) is used by several subsystems.
`strace` does not know which of the several subsystem the device file belongs to, and might not recognize some newer ioctl codes.

The latest `strace` version knows about `SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_PCM_NEXT_DEVICE`.